# Can't find lib via transitive use of sub module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

Android Studio 3.4.2

I has main project (app) that use module **mytransport** like this:

```
app/build.gradle

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    implementation project(':mytransport')

}
```

In **mytransport/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

}
```

In `mytransport` code I success use code like this:

in  `MyProject\mytransport\src\main\java\com\mycompany\android\mytransport\util\MyUtil.java`

snippet:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class JSONUtil {
private static GsonBuilder gsonbuilder = new GsonBuilder();
```

Nice.

Now I want in main app to use **gson** lib.
So in **main app** I try this in

```
MyProject\android\MyProject\app\src\main\java\com\mycompany\android\myproject\main\MainApp.java
```

snippet

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
public class MainApp extends Application {

private static GsonBuilder gsonbuilder = new GsonBuilder();
```

but I get compile error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'GsonBuilder'
```

Why it can't find **gson** lib in **main app**? I use it **TRANSITIVE** by `mytransport` module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `api` instead of `implementation`.

In `mytransport/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   //...
   api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

Just an example.

In `library/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':libraryA')
}
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    api project(':library')
}
```

In your app you will be able to access **both** `library` and `libraryA`.

Using the `implementation` configuration:

In `library/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':libraryA')
}
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
}
```

In this case in your app you can't access the libraryA methods.

Comment: What about this : dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"   ?  This is in library

Comment: @Alex your main app/build.gradle has both of these dependencies. annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion". remove implementation.

Comment: This is the most descriptive answer and easy to understand and it works!!! Thanks @gabriele-mariotti