# When library dependency is added using 'api' does not provide access to their library which is declared using 'implementation' in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

LibA is added inside App module using 'api' and LibB is added inside LibA using 'implementation'.

I am not able  to access LibB inside App, it gives compilation error.

Can anyone explain what is happening here ?, am i missing anything or misunderstanding concept of 'api','implementation' ?.

[image: dependency]

Comment: Use `implementation` for LibA and `api` for LibB.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57010001/cant-find-lib-via-transitive-use-of-sub-module/57014927#57014927)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation can be found in the official documentation of the [Java Library plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html), especially in the [API and Implementation separation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) chapter:

> The plugin exposes two configurations that can be used to declare dependencies: api and implementation. The api configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the implementation configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

The main idea with the APi configuration is to avoid internal dependencies of the library module to leak into the library consummer classpath.

In your case, `LibB` is considered as internal dependency to `LibA`, as it's defined in the `implementation` configuration, therefore you are not supposed to access `LibB` directly in your `App` module .

If you need to consume library `LibB` from `App`, then just declare a direct dependency from `App` to `LibB`, with either `api` or `implementation` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The `api` dependency is basically **transitive** in nature to its upstream projects only.  So in your case, if you want *LibB* to be exposed to *App*, then you can have the dependencies like this -

> *App* with `implementation` dependency to *LibA* and
>   *LibA* with `api` dependency to *LibB*

This will allow *LibB* to be exposed transitively to *App*

But, one should use `api` dependency cautiously and only when needed.